# Blockchain interoperability with polkadot

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template

I am a blockchain developer.Trying to explore blockchain interoperability.

Using substrate node template (https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template), start a local substrate based blockchain then install a fronted template to interact with local blockchain node.This fronted template is responsible for submit transaction and get result.This part i have achieved.

Sorry for asking silly questions,but I am not able to understand how I can create parachain and relay chain and two blockchain communicate.

Pls explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on this here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains